# Comparing two strings in two columns in Excel Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can anybody help me to correct this data? There is a long list of this type of data:

[image]

- If there are columns that are exactly matched, like in row 5 (Harley- harley) it should return 1 or 'true' in column C.
- The columns which are not exactly matched, like in Row 3 (Kerry Sean-Kelvin), it should return 0 or 'false' in column C,
- Where there is little mismatching between two columns as in rows 1, 2, 4, and 6, it should return -1 or 'Mismatched'.

Comment: You'll need to specify what "little mismatching" means. For example, you could say that a two letter match in the beginning or the end qualifies as a "little mismatch", but you have to be specific in order to write an excel formula to test if the condition is met.

Comment: Little mismatch means if there are one or more than one characters mismatched like in row 1 Jessica-Jassica,at row no 6 Sonica is written as Onica.

Comment: Or leave this part,i'l be highly obliged if u could solve first two points.

Comment: Check my answer below, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

`=IF(A1=B1, "1",IF(B1=LEFT(A1,LEN(B1)), "-1", IF(B2=RIGHT(A2,LEN(B2)), "-1", "0")))`

As for "little mismatches", it will only detect cases where B1 is either the prefix or suffix of A1 (so "Sonica" and "onica" will produce "-1").

[image]

Detecting a mismatch by one character anywhere within A1 (like "Jessica" vs "Jassica") is more complex and would require some programming.

Comment: First of all Thanku Atzmon,    See how this formula works:                                                                  John Panesar         John         0
Kerry Sean         Kelvin      -1
Michael Messy         Mi               0
Harley                 harley      -1                                                       
Sonica                 onica       1                                                                 It returns -1 for both harley-Harley and Kerry-Kelvin..??? and 1 for Sonica-onica....???

Comment: Added a screenshot to make sure we're referring to the same results.

Comment: O yess ..Got it...Thanx a lot Atmzon..It's very helpful.....please do favour me to solve the last point..Thanku again...

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this SupeUser answer (being more of a help site that a free code writing site). What you need is some fuzzy logic matching programmed in VBA. Take a look at some implementations of the [Levenshtein Distance algorithm in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel) over at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you  can use the IF function to compare strings and get a results as True or False.

Syntax: IF(A1=B1,"True","False")

If you want to match cases, you can use EXACT function. It checks for case and other characters.

You have to combines these 2 with other string based functions to obtain the results. As your cases are not exactly static.

Comment: thanx , but exact function does not work for huge data. i need macro for correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide for the number of characters that match, I used 3 as limit, if 3 characters matches the result will be -1 if less 0 if all match 1, the formula in C1 and press **Shift + Ctrl + Enter** array Formula and you can drag it:

**=IF(ISNA(IF(A1=B1,1,IF(SUM(MATCH(MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1))),1),MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),0))>3,-1,0))),0,IF(A1=B1,1,IF(SUM(MATCH(MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1))),1),MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),0))>3,-1,0)))**